# How do I find all parent objects that do not have child object with specific property?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda

I have the following entities: Trackings, Ranks

Each Tracking can have 0 or more Ranks. Each Rank has a property called RankDateTime.

I need to find all trackings that have no ranks for today.

This is what I have been trying:

Attempt 1

```
var myTrackings = from track in DBContext.Trackings
            join r in DBContext.Ranks on track.TrackingId equals r.TrackingId
            where r.RankDateTime < DateTime.Today select track;
```

Attempt 2

```
var myTrackings3 =
DBContext.Trackings.Where(t => t.Ranks.Any
(r => r.RankDateTime.Date != DateTime.Today.Date));
```

I'm a bit confused here and my intuition is telling me I'm doing something wrong here.

What's the correct way of querying this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you change the `Any` to `All` in your second attempt, it looks like it should be logically what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there are no RankDateTimes in the future this should work

```
var myTrackings3 = DBContext.Trackings.Where
    (t => !t.Ranks.Any(r => r.RankDateTime.Date >= DateTime.Today.Date));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for for trackings of which all ranks are not for today:

```
var today = DateTime.Today;
var myTrackings3 = DBContext.Trackings
                            .Where(t => t.Ranks.All(r => r.RankDateTime < today));
```

Or, if there are future rankings:

```
var today = DateTime.Today;
var tomorrow = today.AddDays(1);
var myTrackings3 = DBContext.Trackings
                            .Where(t => t.Ranks.All(r => r.RankDateTime < today
                                     && t.Ranks.All(r => r.RankDateTime >= tomorrow
                              ));
```

I deliberately avoid using `r.RankDateTime.Date`, because this would make the expression not *sargable*, i.e. it would disable any indexes on `RankDateTime`.